# Can not aggregate a global field: Mathematical expression

Tags: 7, views

I installed "Physical Fields" and I created a view (block) to display the total weight of the order in the shopping cart.
In my view I added the "price" and "quantity" fields, then I add a "Global: Mathematical Expression" field with "[field_weight] * [quantity]".
I activated the aggregation on the view and I configure the parameters of the group for Global field: Mathematical expression sue "sum".

The view does not work and does not display sums.
I have seen that the field of mathematical expression can not be aggregated.

How do I get the sum of this field ?

Can I do this in the "template.php" file of my theme? If yes, how ?

Here is the export of my view :

Thank you.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'commerce_order_weight';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'commerce_order';
$view->human_name = 'Poids de la commande';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Poids panier';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'plus';
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  7 => '7',
  3 => '3',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Appliquer';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Réinitialiser';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Trier par';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relation: Commande Drupal Commerce : Referenced line items */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['id'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['table'] = 'field_data_commerce_line_items';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['field'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['required'] = TRUE;
/* Relation: Commerce Line item : Referenced products */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_product_product_id']['id'] = 'commerce_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_product_product_id']['table'] = 'field_data_commerce_product';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_product_product_id']['field'] = 'commerce_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_product_product_id']['relationship'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
/* Relation: Commerce Product : Referencing Nœud */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_produit']['id'] = 'field_produit';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_produit']['table'] = 'commerce_product';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_produit']['field'] = 'field_produit';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_produit']['relationship'] = 'commerce_product_product_id';
/* Champ: Commande Drupal Commerce : Identifiant (ID) de la commande */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['id'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['table'] = 'commerce_order';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['field'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Champ: Commerce Product : Poids */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['id'] = 'field_weight';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['table'] = 'field_data_field_weight';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['field'] = 'field_weight';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['relationship'] = 'commerce_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['click_sort_column'] = 'weight';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['group_column'] = 'entity_id';
/* Champ: Commerce Line Item : Quantité */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['id'] = 'quantity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['table'] = 'commerce_line_item';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['field'] = 'quantity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['relationship'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['precision'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['separator'] = '';
/* Champ: SUM(Global : Expression mathématique) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['id'] = 'expression';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['field'] = 'expression';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['group_type'] = 'sum';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['label'] = 'Poids de la commande';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['precision'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['separator'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['expression'] = '[field_weight]*[quantity]';
/* Filtre contextuel: Commande Drupal Commerce : Identifiant (ID) de la commande */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['id'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['table'] = 'commerce_order';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['field'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['exception']['title'] = 'Tout';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['default_argument_type'] = 'commerce_cart_current_cart_order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Critère de filtrage: Commande Drupal Commerce : Type de commande */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'commerce_order';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'commerce_order' => 'commerce_order',
);

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$translatables['commerce_order_weight'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Poids panier'),
  t('plus'),
  t('Appliquer'),
  t('Réinitialiser'),
  t('Trier par'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Line items referenced by commerce_line_items'),
  t('Products referenced by commerce_product'),
  t('Nœud referencing products from field_produit'),
  t('.'),
  t('Poids de la commande'),
  t('Tout'),
  t('Block'),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Views relies on the database to perform aggregation. Since the math field's value does not live in the database it doesn't work.

You can however use [Views Aggregator plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) that uses the calculated values instead.

> this module:
>
> - enumerates group members
> - produces tallies, i.e. textual histograms
> - aggregates on Views PHP code-snippet evalutations
> - can filter out result rows on regexp patterns
> - gives you sorting on Views' Math expressions
> - can process Webform submissions
> - lets you add your own custom aggregation functions

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I want to do this without add-on. How to do with a custom template ? I've created views-view-field--commerce-order-weight--block--expression.tpl.php in the templates folder of my theme. What should I write in this file ?

Comment: It is not what templates are supposed to do... A template is for wrapping HTML tags around predefined variables. You should not be processing any logic in your template files. If you must process logic, do it in a preprocess hook in `template.php` file. I have no idea what to put there, always used the power of modules.